# React Native - Cannot fetch API

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, redux, expo

I am using expo `React Native` for developing my app, `Redux` for state management, `ExpressJS` for backend, `MongoDB` as database.

I am trying to fetch logged-in user data, `JWT` tokens are not saved in cookies. I don't know if cookies work with react native or not? I have tested the API with `postman`, API is working and also `JWT Tokens` are saved in cookies when I test it with `postman` or `thunder-client` VS Code extension. Here is the code:

### Backend:

```
exports.getUserDetails = catchAsyncErrors(async (req, res, next) => {
  const user = await User.findById(req.user.id);

  if (!user) {
    return next(new ErrorHandler("User not found", 404));
  }

  res.status(200).json({
    success: true,
    user,
  });
});
```

### Redux State:

```
export const LoadUser = () => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    dispatch({ type: "LOAD_USER_REQUEST" });
    const { data } = await axios.get(`${API_URL}/api/auth/me`);
    dispatch({
      type: "LOAD_USER_SUCCESS",
      payload: data.user, //Not loading data.
    });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: "LOAD_USER_FAIL",
      payload: error.response.data.message,
    });
  }
};
```

### Frontend App.js file:

```
import { Provider as RNP_Provider } from "react-native-paper";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import Index from "./Index";
import { LoadUser } from "./actions/authAction";
import store from './store'
import { useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {

  useEffect(() => {
    store.dispatch(LoadUser());
  }, [])

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <RNP_Provider>
        <Index />
      </RNP_Provider>
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as cookies in mobile apps created in ReactNative.
What you may use are AsyncStorages for Android/iOS and EncryptedStorage, search for those in npm and read the documentation, I guarantee you'll find your answers there!

You can also use some kind of context if you want your tokens to be saved for one session only, stores are suggested to use for values that you want to save for a longer time.

EncryptedStorage saves values even after app unninstall, so be careful with that one :)

Comment: [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o84x9Tuxky0) I am following this video for authentication. It is in hindi so sorry for language issue, he uses cookies to save tokens. He uploaded the backend on hosting server. So are cookies saved in server's cookie?